# In SWARM not able to access service from worker node

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-swarm, swarm, vmware-player

I am new to the docker world. During learning I have created the below setup:

1.Virtual machine - Ubuntu 20 running on VMware workstation 15 Player. IP - 192.168.0.106. I am able to access the internet from this VM(say it VM1) and able to ping that system from my physical system OS( Windows 10)

2.Virtual Machine - Ubuntu 20 running on VMware workstation 15 Player. IP - 192.168.0.105. I am able to access the internet from this VM(say it VM2) and able to ping that system from my physical system OS( Windows 10)

3. Now I have created the swarm as follows from VM1:

   `sudo docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.0.106:2377 --listen-addr 192.168.0.106:2377`
4. Then I added the VM2 in this swarm as follows:

   `sudo docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-4i56y47l6o4aycrmg7un21oegmfmwnllcsxaf4zxd05ggqg0zh-9qp67bejerq9dhl3f0suaauvl 192.168.0.106:2377 --advertise-addr 192.168.0.105:2377 --listen-addr 192.168.0.105:2377`
5. After that I checked the swarm details:

`sudo docker node ls`

`ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION`

`ogka7rdjohri9elcbjjcpdlbp *   ubuntumaster        Ready               Active              Leader              19.03.12`

`7qu9kiprcz7oowfk2ol31k1mx     ubuntuslave         Ready               Active                                  19.03.13`

6. Then deployed the nginx service as follows from VM1:

   `sudo docker service create -d --name myweb1 --mode global -p9090:80 nginx:1.19.3`
7. Service status:

   `sudo docker service ls`

`ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE               PORTS`

`e1o9cbm3e0t        myweb1              global              2/2                 nginx:1.19.3        *:9090->80/tcp`

8. Service details:

`sudo docker service ps zf6kfw7aqhag`

`ID                  NAME                             IMAGE               NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE            ERROR               PORTS`

`egd8oliwngf3        myweb1.ogka7rdjohri9elcbjjcpdlbp   nginx:1.19.3        ubuntumaster        Running             Running 14 minutes ago`

`1o4q8dlt94jj        myweb1.7qu9kiprcz7oowfk2ol31k1mx   nginx:1.19.3        ubuntuslave         Running             Running 14 minutes ago`

9. Now I am able to access the nginx from VM1 using URL: `192.168.0.106:9090` and `localhost:9090`. But I am not able to access nginx from VM2 using URL: `192.168.0.105:9090` and `localhost:9090`. My understanding that the nginx are running on both the VMs and can be accessible on both.
10. in both the VM1 I am able to see the nginx container is running.

VM1 :

`sudo docker container ls`

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES`

`7a4e13e49dfd        nginx:1.19.3        "/docker-entrypoint.…"   16 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       80/tcp              myweb1.ogka7rdjohri9elcbjjcpdlbp.egd8oliwngf35wwpjcieew323`

VM2:

`sudo docker container ls`

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES`

`999062110f0        nginx:1.19.3        "/docker-entrypoint.…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       80/tcp              myweb1.7qu9kiprcz7oowfk2ol31k1mx.1o4q8dlt94jj4uufysnhsbamd`

Please guide me on this if I am doing any mistakes.

TIA,

Deb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! it was an issue was the ip clashing. Restarted the whole systems including the VM and router to solve this issue.